# VM lost internet connection after connecting host to new network

Tags: wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm running VirtualBox 6.1 on my MacBook Pro (Big Sur 11.2.3) and, through it, an Ubuntu 20.04 VM.  I have two network adapters set up.  One is a bridged adapter and the other is a host-only adapter.

I've notice that, when I connect my laptop to a different wireless network, my VM loses internet connection.  How do I make it so that it automatically is connected to whatever wireless network the host is on?

For reference, here's the result of `ip addr` from within the VM:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:c2:f9:eb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:fb:e3:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.101/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s8
       valid_lft 328sec preferred_lft 328sec
    inet6 fe80::ddad:b2ec:3ee0:ec99/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First at [this site](https://www.nakivo.com/blog/virtualbox-network-setting-guide/) you can get an overview of the networking options within Virtualbox. When creating a bridge you are practically 'gluing' your WiFi adapter on your host together with some 'wired' controller on your VM. But all notion of 'wifi' disappears in the VM and a connection loss of signal is probably not communicated through properly, causing the VM not to take corrective actions (such as obtaining a new DHCP lease).

There are probably two things to try:

1. If the WiFi switch appears, in the VM menu of virtualbox go to Devices -> Network -> 'Connect network adapter' and disable/enable this.  The VM might pick this up as a cable unplug/plug and might fix it.
2. Does your setup allow for use of a NAT on the adapter. If you switch to using NAT (instead of bridged mode), these responsbilities are pushed back to the virtualbox hypervisor to fix these things for you.

Comment: Switching to NAT did it.